# Try to set an icon to a file in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, icons, finder, nsworkspace

I try to get a file icon and to set it back to the same file (goal is to have overlay, but I first want to have this one work):

```
NSImage *img=[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:@"MyFilePath"];
NSLog(@"x=%.f",img.size.width); // Result=32
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:img forFile:@"MyFilePath" options:0];
```

-> Result is that my file gets a standard Finder icon instead of keeping its own icon. Anything I am doing wrong ?

Comment: check if you have write access

Comment: Yes I have. And as the icon is changing towards a finder standard icon (and not towards itself), it means that the rights are there.

Comment: maybe it is too small. I dont think it upscales?

Comment: Tried to set its size to 512x512 (with [img setSize]), same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using it like this:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]
              setIcon: [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"MyFilePath"]
              forFile: @"MyFilePath"
              options: 0];
```

You need to to load the icon/image into memory first.

> EDIT: Answer updated to provide additional information in regards to
>   the comment below.

*"how can I keep the image in memory to "play" with it before reassigning it?"*

The `NSImage` that gets allocated into memory from your specified path can be manipulated in just about any possible way once it's been loaded. You'll want to thoroughly read the [**NSImage Class Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000344-75385) to gain a real understanding of what it does and how use it's methods. For this particular scenario you'll want to be able have a named variable assigned from the icon you load.

Only one change needs to happen with the code above to make it work:

```
NSImage *iconImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"MyFilePath"];

[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]
                setIcon: iconImage
                forFile: @"MyFilePath"
                options: 0];

NSLog(@"iconImage: %@",iconImage);
```

The slight change essentially assigns the variable `iconImage` from the `NSImage` icon; everything else stays the same. The NSLog will give you a very quick glimpse at properties associated with `iconImage` — where you take it from there is really up to your coding ability and creativity.

Comment: OK, with your trick except the fact that the image becomes stretched, the file keeps its icon. However as the icon needs an overlay, how can I keep the image in memory to "play" with it before reassigning it ? Thanks.

Comment: @LaurentCrivello, I've updated my answer pertaining to your comment :)

Comment: Thanks, however this only works if the "MyFilePath" is an image. I tested with a .txt file and the resulting iconImage is nil. So how to retain an iconForFile result ?